# Example of a counting process which is stationary increments but not independent increments

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

What could be an example of a counting process which is stationary increments but not independent increments? (I found an opposite example. Non-homogeneous Poisson process is a counting process which is independent increments but not stationary increments.)

Comment: I found an example. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347941/independent-and-stationary-increments