# Difference between stationarity and independence properties for Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

What is the difference between the stationarity and independence properties of proving that a stochastic process $W(t)$ is Brownian motion?

I only understand that for stationarity, we're trying to show that $W(t+\Delta t) - W(t)$ is independent of $t$ and at best only dependent on $\Delta t$. How do I show independence then or how do I intuitively understand independence?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already know both definitions, so you actually know that both definitions aren't the same and furthermore none is implying the other, which means:

- stationary increments $\not \Rightarrow$ independent increments

For example check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347941/independent-and-stationary-increments) answer, where @Did is constructing an example to match this case.

- independent increments $\not \Rightarrow$ stationary increments

For this to see, just have a look at the non-homogeneous Poisson process, which indeed has independent increments but is not necessarily stationary.

Stationarity means basically, that the distributional properties of $W_t-W_s$ only depend on $(t-s)$, so that  $W_t-W_s \sim W_{t-s}$.

On the other hand independent increments means, that knowing the increment of $W_{t_1}-W_{t_0}$ gives you no distributional information of the increment of any other non-overlapping increment like $W_{t_2}-W_{t_1}$ given $t_0<t_1<\ldots <t_n$.

Form some more intuition on this I recommend to also check some of [these](https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-intuitively-understand-the-concepts-of-the-following-properties-of-a-stochastic-process-stationary-independent-increments-and-the-Markov-property) comments.